# How does the TDA7265 (bridge amplifier) work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, power-amplifier

I'm trying to analyze how op amps work in this circuit:

TDA7265 bridge amplifier

[image: Circuit Diagram 1]

To be specific, I'm not sure in what mode the op amps work here and how to calculate their gains.

Comment: I haven't looked, but are you saying that the datasheet doesn't provide sufficient information for you?

Comment: @jonk
Well, explanation of how the circuit works is not included in datasheet

Comment: Looks to me as though they are using a simple resistor divider to feed back a certain percentage of the output to the NFB input. Do you not know how to compute the resulting gain from that? What's the open loop gain? Do they tell you that much (they had better!) Oh... and do they tell you anything about the minimum closed loop gain?

Comment: @jonk To be honest, I'm not sure how to calculate that, but from the datasheet 
minimum closed loop gain >= 25dB
and open loop voltage gain is 80dB

Comment: Okay. That's sufficient. \$80\:\text{dB}\$ is \$A_{v_o}=10^{^\frac{80}{20}}=10000\$. The \$NFB=\frac{560\:\Omega}{560\:\Omega+36\:\text{k}\Omega}\$, so the resulting closed loop gain is \$A_{v}=\frac{A_{v_o}}{1+A_{v_o}\cdot NFB}\approx 65\$ or \$\approx 36\:\text{dB}\$. That's above the minimum, so that's to the good. You should memorize this stuff (after understanding it.) Haven't you ever looked at how NFB affects closed loop gain before? If not, I could derive it in an answer along with the above info. But I'm happy enough if these comments answer your need, too.

Comment: Thank you for that, I've never seen this equation used in my college course. I've tried calculating It assuming it's an ideal op amp using the virtual ground and the answer is similar.

Comment: It is not an opamp, instead it has two power amplifiers with each one driving one of the speaker wires with opposite phases resulting in almost double the output voltage swing and almost double the output current swing for almost 4 times the output power of a single normal amplifier that uses the same speaker and supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

To analyze the closed-loop gain assuming ideal op-amps you can do a few things to simplify. Ignore the supply bypassing. Ignore the Zoebel networks (R5, C7, R6, C9). Ignore the coupling capacitors and assume DC coupling with a bipolar supply (there is some biasing involved that is not shown). Ignore C8 for now.

Then you have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIwlK0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The bottom of R3 is a virtual ground so Vout of OA1 is: (1+36/1.12)\$\cdot\$ V1 = 33.1 \$\cdot\$ V1.

|Output| of OA2 is a bit less (no '+1' factor): -(36/1.12)\$\cdot\$V1 = -32.2\$\cdot\$ V1, so voltage gain is 65.3 or 36.3dB.

Comment: Thanks! I was just calculating It using this method. It's good to know that I actually did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage gain of the top amplifier is (36k/560)+1= 65.3 and the same for the bottom amplifier.
Since the two amplifiers are bridged then the output gain is double the single amplifier gain so the total gain is 130.6 times.